# with protractor how to setup internet explorer configuration?

Tags: windows, angularjs, internet-explorer, protractor

I am using protractor 1.3.1 and running iedriverserver.exe 2.43.0.0 with IE11 installed (windows).
This is my spec:

```
describe('quick test IE driver', function () {
    it('should go to ng homepage', function () {
        browser.driver.get('https://angularjs.org/');
        var title =element(by.css('h1')).getText();
        expect(title).toBe('HTML enhanced for web apps!');
    });
});
```

And this is my protractor.conf.js:

```
exports.config = {
    // The address of a running selenium server.
    //seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'internet explorer',
        'platform': 'ANY',
        'version': '11'
    },


    // Spec patterns are relative to the current working directly when
    // protractor is called.
    specs: ['main.spec.js'],

    // Options to be passed to Jasmine-node.
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
        isVerbose:true,
        includeStackTrace:true

    }
};
```

getting this error though, any ideas for a solution:

```
UnknownError: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.ie.driver system property;
```

Comment: I am felling your pain bro. I am experiencing the same. :/

Answer (score 14):

Update web manager for IE

First step is to update the ie webdriver using webdriver manager.Open command prompt and run the command given below

```
webdriver-manager update --ie
```

Go to npm location In this step move to the NPM_LOCATION(folder where npm is installed at your system. Move to the following path "NPM_LOCATION\node_modules\protractor\selenium" At this location check that IEDriverServer.exe is present or not.

Change for IE in conf.js

```
// conf.js exports.config = {   seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',   specs: ['specs.js'],   capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'internet explorer' // conf for internet explorer     } }


// spec.js describe('Protractor Demo App', function() {   it('should have a title', function() {
    browser.get('http://juliemr.github.io/protractor-demo/');
    expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('Super Calculator');   }); });
```

Now run protractor conf.js

Note: Make sure you restart server by -->webdriver-manager start

taken from: http://protractorsupport.blogspot.com/2015/05/use-protractor-with-internet-explorer.html

Comment: if `webdriver-manager` is not in the global path, I'm guessing I need to install that via npm? with `-g` ?

Answer (score 8):

According to [the protractor config doc](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts#L38), **the config value `"seleniumArgs"` is deprecated**.

So, to have a single answer with all the info, here are the simplified steps:

1. Install Protactor globally:

   ```
   npm install -g protractor
   ```
2. Run [`webdriver-manager update --ie`](https://github.com/angular/webdriver-manager) to update the Selenium drivers that Protactor uses. Be aware if you are running the **global** `webdriver-manager` or the **local** `webdriver-manager` (i.e `./node_modules./bin/webdriver-manager update help`); they will unzip the drivers at separate locations; only the **local** will unzip in `[Project dir]`
3. Take a look at the log of the previous command. It must show that the drivers were unzipped at a particular folder. Go to that folder and locate the IEDriverServer. In my case it was: `"[Project dir]\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\IEDriverServer_x64_X.XX.X.exe`. You will need to give the relative path to this file in the next step.
4. Inside your `conf.js` file, add the following keys & values. Note the use of `localSeleniumStandaloneOpts`, which means you should *remove* the property [`seleniumAddress` if you have it](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts#L88):

   ```
   multiCapabilities : [
     {
       'browserName' : 'chrome'
     }, {
       'browserName' : 'internet explorer'
     }
   ],

   localSeleniumStandaloneOpts : {
     jvmArgs : ["-Dwebdriver.ie.driver=<RELATIVE PATH TO IE DRIVER>"] // e.g: "node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/IEDriverServer_x64_X.XX.X.exe"
   },
   ```

That was all I needed to do. I don't start the server beforehand, I simply run `protactor conf.js`. Easier now, I guess.

Comment: Thank you - this is the correct answer now for running 'out of the box' against IE without setting up a separate selenium / web-driver instance, the above answers do not work for that use case.

Answer (score 4):

Download the IEDriverServer.exe 
Please specify the same in your config file

```
seleniumArgs: ['-Dwebdriver.ie.driver=<path to IEDriverServer.exe>']
```

Comment: [According to the protractor config doc, the config value "seleniumArgs" is deprecated.](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts#L45)

Answer (score 3):

I was looking around this question for few hours, the best way seems to be:

1) download 
webdriver-manager --ie update

This should download the driver from the google.. selenium ... release folder and place it directly in the good place in your npm local repository.

2) setup in config.js file of your tests:
...

```
multiCapabilities: [
    //{
    //    browserName: 'chrome',
    //    version: 'ANY'
    //},
    //{
    //    browserName: 'firefox',
    //    version: 'ANY'
    //},
    {
        browserName: 'internet explorer',
        version: 'ANY'
    },
],
// For some IE functions you may need to specify defaultTimeoutInterval
```

...
3) setup IE:

follow this post
http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.fr/2012/08/youre-doing-it-wrong-protected-mode-and.html

PS: about the "protected mode" setup of IE, it's important to have the same setup for all zones. I prefer to have protected mode 'on' for all zone

4) patch the registry

as described here: http://heliumhq.com/docs/internet_explorer

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE]
"iexplore.exe"=dword:00000000

5) IE 11 update break the way the system work:

My lastest issue was "the server did not provide any stack trace ...." this is due to an update of the 17th of Dec 2014. Uninstall it and then it's good.

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3390

crazy path to make it running. It cannot be like this for a long run, please comment my post with your experiences/feedbacks.

Richard

Comment: I just want to add a little update that they have added a --ie32 option that will install the 32bit driver. The 64bit driver is pretty much broken due to sendKeys() taking several seconds per key stroke. Please note that you must also add the --ie32 switch to the start command as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my config file:

```
exports.config = {

seleniumAddress: 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',
capabilities: {
'browserName': 'internet explorer',
 },

framework: 'jasmine',

// Spec patterns are relative to the current working directory when
// protractor is called.
specs: ['your_spec_file.js'],
```

};

The steps to run in IE :

1. Need two terminals in Visual Studio Code, 
   In the first terminal, Run command "webdriver-manager start" to start selenium server.
2. In the second terminal, Run your js config file as :
   Protractor conffile_name.js

This will successfully start Internet explorer.
Thanks