# Unable to run the protractor test

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I am going through the tutorial at http://www.protractortest.org/#/tutorial and want to run the protractor tests.

The first problem I faced is that when running the `webdriver-manager update` I got the certificate issues as mentioned in this thread [Can't update chromedriver and seleniumrelease](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29483126/cant-update-chromedriver-and-seleniumrelease)

So, I manually downloaded the `chromedriver_win32.zip` and `selenium-server-standalone-2.47.1.jar`

I then extracted the zip file and placed `chromedriver.exe` at the same folder `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\selenium`

Then I started the server and I ran the test `protractor conf.js`

I got the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property;
```

I am aware that it is missing the path to chromedriver.exe which I need to specify as a system property, so taking a que from this thread for i.e. [with protractor how to setup internet explorer configuration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26395216/with-protractor-how-to-setup-internet-explorer-configuration) I put the following in the conf.js

```
exports.config = {
  framework: 'jasmine2',
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['spec.js']
  seleniumArgs: ['-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\selenium\chromedriver.exe']
}
```

But still I am getting the same error, I know I am missing something very simple but not sure what!

Comment: What if you would run `node_modules\protractor\bin\protractor conf.js` instead?

Comment: I am trying to run protractor conf.js from the folder inside which conf.js and  spec.js is present, are you suggesting it to give the absolute path to proctractor executable?

Comment: Yes, to use an absolute path and point it to the protractor inside the node_modules in your project root. It's just wild guess, but give it a try.

Comment: I am getting this error 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\bin\protractor' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 0):

We were having the same issue like you, what we did is added the following in the config

```
directConnect: true,
chromeDriver: 'C:\\tools\\selenium\\chromedriver',//this will be your path to chromedriver FOLDER
```

cheers